# How can I hide the toggle element in html

Tags: html, css

```css
body .ramji_wrapper {
  width: 225px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #2a394f;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label {
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  height: 72px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #293649;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #eff4fa;
  
  -webkit-transition: text-indent .15s, height .3s;
  transition: text-indent .15s, height .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 16px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label span {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label:hover {
  background: #212e41;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2A394F;
  text-indent: 4px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label:hover .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label .bar {
  width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width .15s;
  transition: width .15s;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #355789;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label .lil_arrow {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  right: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content li {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1  inset;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s,text-indent .3s;
  transition: box-shadow .3s,text-indent .3s;
  position: relative;
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content li:hover {
  background: #0c93e4;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px #126CA1  inset;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s linear,text-indent .3s linear;
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear,text-indent .3s linear;
  text-indent: 31px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

input[type='radio']:checked + label .ramji_wrapper__content {
  display: block;
  top: 68px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212e41;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label > .lil_arrow {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  border-top: 2px solid #14a3f9;
  border-right: 2px solid #14a3f9;
}

input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  height: 325px;
  background: #212e41;
  text-indent: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: height;
  transition-property: height;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .6s;
          transition-duration: .6s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='radio']:checked + label .bar {
  width: 0;
}

input[type='radio']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='radio']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='radio']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='radio']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  from {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes in {
  from {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class='ramji_wrapper'>
    <input id='Dashboard' name='radio' type='radio'>
    <label for='Dashboard'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/dash.png'>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Tools</li>
          <li>Reports</li>
          <li>Analytics</li>
          <li>Code Blocks</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Sales' name='radio' type='radio'>
    <label for='Sales'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/del.png'>
      <span>Sales</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>New Sales</li>
          <li>Expired Sales</li>
          <li>Sales Reports</li>
          <li>Deliveries</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Messages' name='radio' type='radio'>
    <label for='Messages'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/mess.png'>
      <span>Messages</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Inbox</li>
          <li>Outbox</li>
          <li>Sent</li>
          <li>Archived</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Users' name='radio' type='radio'>
    <label for='Users'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/users.png'>
      <span>Users</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>New User</li>
          <li>User Groups</li>
          <li>Permissions</li>
          <li>Passwords</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Settings' radio='radio' type='radio'>
    <label for='Settings'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/set.png'>
      <span>Settings</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Databases</li>
          <li>Design</li>
          <li>Change User</li>
          <li>Log Out</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>

> the  code is showing the contents after i click the little arrow. but again if i click the little arrow it is not closing(hiding). please tell me the changes that I have to do
```

> the  code is showing the contents after i click the little arrow. but again if i click the little arrow it is not closing(hiding). please tell me the changes that I have to do

Comment: You should make the checkbox as input field , type='checkbox'  because radio just turns true only once. I mean It does not toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `checkbox` instead of `radio`. With `radio` once it's checked it can't be unchecked by clicking it again. Only another one can be selected. This won't be an issue with checkbox though. The only downside is that all can be open at once:

```css
body .ramji_wrapper {
  width: 225px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #2a394f;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label {
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  height: 72px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #293649;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #eff4fa;
  
  -webkit-transition: text-indent .15s, height .3s;
  transition: text-indent .15s, height .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 16px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label span {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label:hover {
  background: #212e41;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2A394F;
  text-indent: 4px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label:hover .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label .bar {
  width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width .15s;
  transition: width .15s;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #355789;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
body .ramji_wrapper label .lil_arrow {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  right: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content li {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1  inset;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s,text-indent .3s;
  transition: box-shadow .3s,text-indent .3s;
  position: relative;
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content li:hover {
  background: #0c93e4;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px #126CA1  inset;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s linear,text-indent .3s linear;
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear,text-indent .3s linear;
  text-indent: 31px;
}
body .ramji_wrapper__content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
display: none;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label .ramji_wrapper__content {
  display: block;
  top: 68px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212e41;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label > .lil_arrow {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  border-top: 2px solid #14a3f9;
  border-right: 2px solid #14a3f9;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
  height: 325px;
  background: #212e41;
  text-indent: 4px;
  -webkit-transition-property: height;
  transition-property: height;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .6s;
          transition-duration: .6s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label .bar {
  width: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  from {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes in {
  from {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='ramji_wrapper'>
    <input id='Dashboard' name='radio' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Dashboard'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/dash.png'>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Tools</li>
          <li>Reports</li>
          <li>Analytics</li>
          <li>Code Blocks</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Sales' name='radio' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Sales'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/del.png'>
      <span>Sales</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>New Sales</li>
          <li>Expired Sales</li>
          <li>Sales Reports</li>
          <li>Deliveries</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Messages' name='radio' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Messages'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/mess.png'>
      <span>Messages</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Inbox</li>
          <li>Outbox</li>
          <li>Sent</li>
          <li>Archived</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Users' name='radio' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Users'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/users.png'>
      <span>Users</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>New User</li>
          <li>User Groups</li>
          <li>Permissions</li>
          <li>Passwords</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Settings' radio='radio' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Settings'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/set.png'>
      <span>Settings</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='ramji_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Databases</li>
          <li>Design</li>
          <li>Change User</li>
          <li>Log Out</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks a ton... onething is that, it is showing checkboxes at the top. whatever contents I clicked it is ticking at the top. I do not want that.. how can i modify that?

Comment: You should just be able to set them to `display: none`. Something like this should work `input[type='checkbox'] {display: none;}`. Hiding them is the only option really to stop them being visible.

Comment: It should be working. I've just updated the answer and it's all working there.